# How to add range slider to rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want add range slider filter to my app with "bootstrap-slider" but I don't know how to add html attributes to text_field_tag. I need the below attributes in text_field_tag

```
data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]"
```

Form

```
    <%= form_tag @sub_category, method: 'get' do |d| %>
    <%= text_field_tag "ex2", type: 'text',
                 data: {'slider-id' => 'ex1Slider',
                        'slider-min' => '10',
                        'slider-max' => '1000',
                        'slider-step' => '5',
                        'slider-value' => '[250,450]' }
 %>
    <% end %>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#ex2").slider({});
});
</script>
```

Generated html

```
<input id="ex2" name="ex2" type="text" value="{:type=>"text", :data=>{"slider-id"=>"ex1Slider", "slider-min"=>"10", "slider-max"=>"1000", "slider-step"=>"5", "slider-value"=>"[250,450]"}}" style="display: none;">
```

Script doesnt work after this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter for text_field_tag is value: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

You need to add nil after the name of the tag "ex2" and you don't need type: 'text' since that's the default but you can keep it if you want to.

```
<%= text_field_tag "ex2", nil, type: 'text',
                 data: {'slider-id' => 'ex1Slider',
                        'slider-min' => '10',
                        'slider-max' => '1000',
                        'slider-step' => '5',
                        'slider-value' => '[250,450]' }
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the text_field_tag is the value. [Check the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)

Here is how the code will be

```
<%= text_field_tag "ex2", nil, :data => {'slider-id' => 'ex1Slider','slider-min' => '10','slider-max' => '1000','slider-step' => '5','slider-value' => '[250,450]'  }%>
```